# Angularfire snapshotChanges() vs Firestore javscript library onSnapshot()

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I found there's two realtime listener for firestore.

- Angularfire: snapshotChanges()
- Firestore javscript library: onSnapshot()

Here is my question

1. May I know what is the difference? How should I use them properly (I'm developing using Ionic + Cordova + Angular framework)?
2. How to detach snapshotChanges()? Refer to Firestore documentation, I can detach onSnapshot() as per below.

```
    var unsubscribe = db.collection("cities")
        .onSnapshot(function (){
          // Respond to data
          // ...
        });

    // Later ...

    // Stop listening to changes
    unsubscribe();
```

Thanks for your kind sharing.

Comment: where did u see onsnasphot in angularfire?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. I had updated my post already which onsnapshot() is from JS web library and snapshotChanges() is from angularfirestore.

Seem I able to use onsnapshot under angularfirestore as well, both working just fine, so I wonder what's the difference between them, what is the best case to use each of them.
 
listener = this.afs.doc(`test/${id}/`).ref.onSnapshot()
listener = this.afs.doc(`test/${id}/`).snapshotChanges().subscribe()

Comment: if u are using angularfire then just use `snapshotChanges()`, if you are using the js web library then use `onSnapshot()`, both will retrieve the data in realtime. But `snapshotChanges()` is a method in the library angularfire which you use when working in an angular project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AngularFire library does not contain a method called `onSnapshot()`. The [`onSnapshot()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen) method is used in the javascript cloud firestore library, to listen for realtime updates.

While the `snapshotChanges()` is specifically for angularfire it returns an `Observable` therefore it will keep listening for any changes in the database and retrieve the data.

To `unsubscribe`, you just need to call the method [`unsubscribe()`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Subscription.js~Subscription.html#instance-method-unsubscribe):

```
//Subscribe
subscription = this.itemRef.snapshotChanges().subscribe();

//Unsubscribe
subscription.unsubscribe()
```

Comment: What does the Observable returned by snapshotChanges() hold?

Comment: the Observable will observe the stream of data coming from the reference location, and then when you get call `subscribe()` you can access the data. @arcrub